# Widgets: Show Recent Posts Only if the Posts Have Both Categories X and Y

Tags: wp-query, widgets, categories

I've been trying to create a Recent Post widget where it only show/display posts that have both categories X and Y (or more). The categories X and Y is user-defined, so I'm planning to make it look like this:

[image]

In fact, that picture is an actual screenshot from what I have managed to create.

It is working fine if I select only from one category. It would show all posts which have the category of X (or X's children). However, if I add one more category, it would stop working--instead, the widget would show all recent posts regardless of categories.

[image]

For creating this code, basically I copied the `widget_recent_posts` class from `default-widget.php` and add a field for ID input. It utilizes `WP_query` to query the posts and `category__and` to select the post:

```
$r = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'widget_posts_args', array( 'posts_per_page' => $number, 'no_found_rows' => true, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'category__and' => array($category_name), 'ignore_sticky_posts' => true ) ) );
```

What I have created so far (the full class) is available here: http://codepad.org/yf1ZFAt5

I'd be really thankful if anyone could hep me, as I have been messing around with this one for hours but haven't managed to tackle it. :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using `'category__and' => array($category_name)` which according to the input becomes `'category__and' => array('594,3')`

Here '594,3' is not a valid id

instead try `'category__and' => explode(',', $category_name)`

This will make the input as `'category__and' => array('594', '3')`

Comment: Hmm... with `'category__and' => explode(',', $category_name)`, it doesn't show anything at all (the whole widget, including the widget title, seems to be gone)... while I tried with `'category__and' => array(explode(',', $category_name))`, it shows posts from the `Uncategorized` category. :s Should this be put on `WP_Query` (when querying the post) or on other places?

Comment: I have just realized that `category__and` *does not* display child categories... I guess this is why using `category__and` shows nothing, because most of all posts are categorized under 594's children, not the category 594 itself... oddly it did show the children when I was experimenting back then though. :| Now I guess my question changes to... how is it possible to make `category__and` always includes children?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to do that directly. You'll have to query the ID's of child categories once & then put them all in `category__and`

Comment: Hmm, in the end it gets complicated... and I guess I'd go for a `cat` instead :s Thanks anyway!